# Lost connection to device when loading a tflite model flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, model, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

[image: Debug process]

Although I've connected another model in the same code and it works fine. When loading this model, The device gets disconnected. Anybody know what could be wrong? Is it the dimensions entered or is it with the `tflite model`?

Comment: Welcome salma, please put the error log as text , not as image .

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with shape [1, 1000] to a Java object with shape [1, 174].